# loop through read_csv files python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

First time post, Python newbie, appreciate your help and patience. Looking for help iterating through read_csv() files and assigning each to their own new dataframe. The 'filesnames' get pulled in correctly, just having issues making a unique dataframe for each csv imported.

```
#makes a variable list of filenames with common patterns via glob
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('617*.txt'))

#gets the number of files from folder
count = len(filenames)    

i =0
for i in range(0, count): 
    file = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/fjehlik/Desktop/python\
    data_frame_excel/'+filenames[i], sep = '\t', header=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you want to create a dictionary of DataFrames:

```
dfs = {f:pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t') for f in filenames}
```